# three.js After importing the model through objloader, how to make the model have physical effect through physijs?

Tags: three.js, physijs

I know through Physijs.BoxMesh Can let three.js The model has a physical effect

```
new Physijs.BoxMesh(Geometry, material, 1)
```

But now my model is imported through objloader. How can I make it have physical effect

```
var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
objLoader.load(baseUrl+"sofa/1/file.obj", function(mesh){
    mesh.scale.set(0.115, 0.115, 0.115);
    mesh.rotateY(-Math.PI/2);
    mesh.position.set(-105, 0, 80);
    scene.add(mesh);
})
```

Comment: I got it!


objLoader.load('xxx.obj',function(object){
  var model = object;

  for (let x in model.children){
    let material = Physijs.createMaterial(model.children[x].material, 1, 0);
    let mesh = new Physijs.BoxMesh(model.children[x].geometry, material, 0);
    mesh.castShadow = true;
    mesh.receiveShadow = true;

    scene.add(mesh);
  }
},onProgress,onError);

Answer (score 1):

You could extract the geometry from the loaded `mesh` and use it to create your own `Physijs.BoxMesh`:

```js
var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
var boxMesh;
objLoader.load(baseUrl+"sofa/1/file.obj", function(mesh){
    boxMesh = new Physijs.BoxMesh(mesh.geometry, mesh.material);
    boxMesh.scale.set(0.115, 0.115, 0.115);
    boxMesh.rotateY(-Math.PI/2);
    boxMesh.position.set(-105, 0, 80);
    scene.add(boxMesh);
})
```

Comment: The physical effect generated by boxmesh is not correct. Sometimes there is nothing around, but the result shows collision effect, and sometimes there are objects around but they pass through

Comment: I think someone said concavemesh. But the browser reported an error.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at new window.Physijs.Physijs.ConcaveMesh (physi.js:1259)